# Android TCP Socket Error

Tags: android, tcp, socketexception

i recently wanted to create an application on android which connects to a c# server via tcp. The Server is created and listens also Ports are opened.

The Problem is the error which my android application causes:

```
    07-20 02:11:52.057 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-20 02:11:52.122 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 D/MyApp: I am here
07-20 02:11:52.122 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
07-20 02:11:52.122 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:619)
07-20 02:11:52.122 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:198)
07-20 02:11:52.122 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:584)
07-20 02:11:52.122 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:128)
07-20 02:11:52.122 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
07-20 02:11:52.122 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)
07-20 02:11:52.123 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at connector.de.connect2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
07-20 02:11:52.123 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
07-20 02:11:52.123 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
07-20 02:11:52.123 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
07-20 02:11:52.123 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2520)
07-20 02:11:52.123 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
07-20 02:11:52.123 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
07-20 02:11:52.123 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-20 02:11:52.123 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
07-20 02:11:52.123 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
07-20 02:11:52.123 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-20 02:11:52.123 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
07-20 02:11:52.123 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-20 02:11:52.123 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
07-20 02:11:52.123 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
07-20 02:11:52.123 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:282)
07-20 02:11:52.123 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:604)
07-20 02:11:52.123 1262-1262/connector.de.connect2 W/System.err:    ... 18 more
```

I read that my application is missing the following code in the manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I tried many versions including "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE", "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" etc.

Either nothing changes and the error still appears or the app crashes completely.

I dont know what to do.

If it also helps the code of the application itself is here:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("MyApp","I am here");
        try
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.3", 1071);
            PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())));
            pw.println("Hello");
            socket.close();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And here the Manifest.xml with the tried changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="connector.de.connect2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    <use-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <use-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <use-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logcat output you've provided doesn't show it for some reason, but you cannot perform network operations on the main thread (e.g. inside of `onCreate()`).  You need to offload network operations to a background thread of some kind.

Comment: Thank you, i would upvote your post but i haven't reached the minimum of 15 points. I'll do that later :)

Comment: No problem, hopefully you've been able to get past this by moving things off the main thread.